# Lock Screen on my email sending page asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

i have a page wherein i need to lock the screen when user clicks on the send email button, but everything is happening except i am unable to see my lock screen page. i have used the update progress for this purpose.. m posting part of the code here 
**.aspx part**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="SendMailUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div style="float: right;">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send" ToolTip="Send "
                Visible="false" Font-Bold="True" OnClick="btnSendResume_Click" />                          
            <asp:Button ID="btnDown" runat="server" Text="Download IDs" ToolTip="follow-up"
                Visible="false" Font-Bold="True" OnClick="btnDownloadEmailIDs_Click" />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
    <table>
        <td style="width: auto; vertical-align: top;">
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="SendMailUpdatePanel">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    <div id="blur" style="width: 100%; background-color: black; moz-opacity: 0.5; khtml-opacity: .5;
                        opacity: .5; filter: alpha(opacity=50); z-index: 120; height: 100%; position: absolute;
                        top: 0; left: 0;">
                        <div id="progress" style="z-index: 200; background-color: White; position: absolute; top: 0pt;
                            left: 0pt; border: solid 1px black; padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; text-align: center;">
                            <b>Mail in progress.Please Wait...</b>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
        </td>
    </table>
```

.cs part

```
protected void btnSendResume_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

}
```

rest of the part i have not mentioned here...any help

Comment: I tried the example from [this post](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updateprogress-control/) which looks very similar to your setup and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML Table is incorrectly formed.  You have no `<tr>` elements, but the real problem probably lies with your style attributes, please see my updated code below.

You can find a good example of how to accomplish what you are trying to do here: http://blogs.visoftinc.com/2008/03/13/Modal-UpdateProgress-for-UpdatePanel-Revisited/

Try adjusting your code to the following:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="SendMailUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div style="float: right;">
            <asp:Button ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send" ToolTip="Send "
                Visible="false" Font-Bold="True" OnClick="btnSendResume_Click" />                          
            <asp:Button ID="btnDown" runat="server" Text="Download IDs" ToolTip="follow-up"
                Visible="false" Font-Bold="True" OnClick="btnDownloadEmailIDs_Click" />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="SendMailUpdatePanel">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div id="blur" style="position:fixed; top:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px; overflow:hidden; padding:0; margin:0; background-color:black; filter:alpha(opacity=50); opacity:0.5; z-index:1000;" />
        <div id="progress" style="position:fixed; top:30%; left:43%; width:14%; z-index:1001; background-color:white; border:solid 1px black; padding:5px; text-align:center;">
            <b>Mail in progress.Please Wait...</b>
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Comment: actually m sorry i have placed tr in my code still its not seen

Comment: @user648372 I have updated my code and I think this should work for you.  I have removed the table altogether because I'm not sure what the point of it was, if there is more to it than shown above, I'll let you worry about adding it back in :)

Comment: still i havent able to achieve that...i am unable to add script manger to this page it is saying u cant create two instances of script manger if i do and @chris i have used ur code but still cant c on the click of that button....does the page needs to be ajaxified prior o canu suggest jquery solution if this is not possible.

Comment: i have solved the problem earlier my button was triggered using potbacktrigger now i changed it to async trigger which solved it!!

Comment: <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSend" EventName="Click" />

Comment: now the div element is fixed can we have dat float across the screen while scrolling, the progresstemplate gets lost in the top of the window???ny solution??